# installing octave on kali linux?

Tags: linux, fortran, octave

I am try to install octave on my kali linux

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.6.3.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.6.3.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.6.3
./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

this is what i tried but in last i am getting error

```
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of ... 
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... configure: error: in `/root/Desktop/octave-3.8.0':
configure: error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
See `config.log' for more details
```

any help  new to linux,octave?

Comment: You need to install gfortran!

Comment: For a newbie I would recommend to find binaries for your distro. Which Linux distribution you have?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you go to compile any source code make sure you read the documentation for what the dependencies are.

I was just able to build this on Kali Linux with installing these development packages and libraries from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libqhull5 libqhull-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libfltk1.3-dev
```

Then try:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

You will lose some functionality with Octave just installing these only but `./configure` will tell you what you need to install to enable those features.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the standard kail apt sources, octave should be in your repository.

```
apt-get install octave
```

It does not appear kali has gfortran and I don't recommend you attempt to build that from source.

Also consider that whatever program you installed kali to get access to will run on any other linux distro and you could choose something more user friendly to get started with.

Comment: main reason to build something from source when it's present on the distro repos, is if the version there is old. This makes `build-dep` a bad choice to get its dependencies, specially in Octave (it will install unnecessary stuff, and possibly miss new dependencies). The Octave wiki has build instructions for [Debian based systems](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian), including package names.

Comment: @carandraug that is true, but it appears the kali repo has octave 3.8.2 in it, which is newer than what he's trying to build.   It also looks like it has debian wheezy 3.6.2 build of octave as well.